# Is there a way to get realtime logged in users in Asp.net zero public site (Asp.net MVC)?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr, abp

I am making a web application using Asp.net zero [version 10.2.0]
with ABP Framework version 6.2
Frontend is in Angular 11 & Backend APIs in Asp.net core 5.0 whereas Public website is in Asp.net MVC.

I am trying to fetch logged in users on both frontend(Angular) as well as public(Asp.net MVC) website using SignalR to show it on admin dashboard. Both are using same db table ABPUsers. Does anyone have done similar thing using SignalR or other way ?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar with SignalR on ASP.NET (not Core).  I overloaded the `OnConnected` and `OnDisconnected` methods in the `Hub` class to keep my own Dictionary of connected clients.

Each client has a header with their login information.  In `OnConnected`, I would parse the header and check if this client is already connected.  If they are not, I would add them to the dictionary.  In `OnDisconnected`, I would check if this client is connected and if they are, remove them from the dictionary.  This way, the dictionary always has the connected clients.

**Note:**  because a new `Hub` is created for every new login, the dictionary has to be a singleton or static.  I use a **static** `ConcurrentDictionary`.

**Note 2:** SignalR has an internal structure for storing all clients but it is not possible to easily search without modifying the library and has very limited public methods.  This is why I used my own Dictionary.

Comment: Just watch out that one client/login can have multiple tabs open. So you need to save the specific connection ID for the user and only delete that from your collection. And when all connection ID's for a user are removed then the user is disconnected.

Comment: I use the header data to identify the specific client/user.  ConnectionID is not useful for that.